# Select para año actual

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una sentencia select que me muestra el año actual y el anterior:

```
select year(now()) as actual, YEAR(NOW() - interval 1 year) as anterior;
```

Como resultado esta sencia me dá lo siguiente:

```
 actual  | anterior
===================
  2018      2017
```

Mi problema es que nosé como poner la sentencia de manera que quede así:

```
 años
=======
 2018
 2017
```

Alguna ayuda??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz un union con 2 select (una para cada año)

```
SELECT YEAR(NOW()) as annos
UNION 
SELECT YEAR(NOW() - interval 1 year) as annos
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias! Arreglado

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos.